# Mounting shared directory at boot in CentOS (VirtualBox)

Tags: networking, automounting

this seems to be a common question but I still can't find an answer that works. I have two CentOS VMs running under VirtualBox 5.2.6.

I've successfully mounted a directory from VM1 onto VM2, and edited /etc/fstab by adding the following line:

```
server1@192.168.56.101:/home/server1 /home/server2/newdir fuse.sshfs defaults,IdentityFile=/home/server2/.ssh/id_rsa 0 0
```

I can run `umount` and then run `mount -a` which works - although I'm still prompted for a password which I wouldn't have expected considering I presented an identity file - perhaps I misunderstood what the ssh key authentication can do...

When rebooting server2 or server1 my shared directory disappears unless I run `mount -a` again. I've seen that I could add `mount -a` to .bashrc so that it gets executed at start-up but I was wondering whether anyone can see something obvious I'm doing wrong/have misunderstood about how this should work without requiring an edit to .bashrc.

All help much appreciated.

Comment: First, check why the rsa authentication isn't working. Become root and try `ssh -i /home/server2/.ssh/id_rsa server1@192.168.56.101`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Running the above command as root (or as user) still prompts for a password and once entered I'm logged into the bash environment on server1. However I can `ssh server1@192.168.56.101` without being prompted for a password and I'm logged into user server1.

Comment: Add the `-v` option to the command line that works and see which identity file it uses.

Comment: Mmm, strange sequence of events - I'm definitely not understanding something!

I used ssh-copy-id (again) to see if that brought back any functionality. I can now run `ssh server1@192.168.56.101` and `ssh -i /home/server2/.ssh/id_rsa server1@192.168.56.101` without being prompted for a password.

Running `ssh -v server1@192.168.56.101` requires a password to log in. I looked through the log which shows it looks for a bunch of root directories for /.ssh whereas my .ssh is in /home/server2/.ssh

I'm guessing I could add this directory somehow to ssh_config to make it work.

Comment: Anyway... despite having password-less log-in. Running mount -a (using the same /etc/fstab edit as before which was previously working) returns "no such file or directory"

Comment: It's good that `ssh -i /home/server2/.ssh/id_rsa server1@192.168.56.101` works. Does it work if you run it when you're root? The mount command runs as root.

Comment: I was running `sudo mount -a`. I said my /etc/fstab was identical but I was wrong because I'd been messing about with it (replaced fuse.sshfs with fuse). I've now returned /etc/fstab to the line described in my OP and success! I can now log in without a password and my shared directory mounts at boot. Thanks for your help, I have one last issue which is that I get a permission denied error if I try to access the shared directory as user server2, but no problems as root. Do I need to add server2 to some group?

Comment: Ah... I can add the "allow_other" option to /etc/fstab to achieve this. Great, everything works and I think I understand where and why things were going wrong. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: It sounds like the fix was to get the correct rsa public key copied over. If you want to, you can answer this question yourself in the text box below; it may help other people with the same problem

Comment: Good idea, added an answer below and hopefully people can see this comment chain too which may provide further troubleshooting for anyone else looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the initial issue was to run ssh-copy-id again which allowed me to mount without being asked for a password. I think this function overwrites the key currently there so shouldn't cause a conflict if you run it twice.

Additional troubleshooting where I needed to add "allow_other" option to my /etc/fstab file